# Cython says buffer types only allowed as function local variables even for ndarray.copy()

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am new to Cython and encountered this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

testarray = np.arange(5)
cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] testarray1 = testarray.copy()
cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] testarray2 = testarray.astype(np.float)
```

During compilation, it said `Buffer types only allowed as function local variables`. However, I am using `.copy()` or `.astype()` which is returning not a memoryview, but a copy. Why is this still happening? How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: `testarray` itself is a buffer. So why not put everything into a function and call it from Python?

Comment: @Midnighter Thanks! I was trying to define some global constants to save several lines of code... And I never thought that `testarray` is a buffer itself before. Thanks for the input - I'd go with more verbose code then I guess! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you define an array in cython using `np.ndarray[Type, dim]`, that is accessing the python buffer interface, and those can't be set as module level variables. This is a separate issue from views vs copies of numpy array data.

Typically if I want to have an array as a module level variable (i.e not local to a method), I define a [typed memoryview](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) and then set it within a method using something like (untested):

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef np.int_t[:] testarray1

def init_arrays(np.int_t[:] testarray):
    global testarray1
    testarray1 = testarray.copy()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josh! It is very helpful. However, the `memoryviewslice` would not have ndarray methods such as ndarray.mean() or ndarray.max()... Any chance you know a workaround?

Comment: As long as it doesn't incur too much overhead for what you're doing, you can use `np.asarray` to coerce the typed memoryview to a numpy array http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy within the method that you are using the memoryview in.

Comment: Excellent! That is awesome functionality that I didn't notice. Thank you so much Josh!

Comment: Why do you use `testarray.copy()` instead of just `testarray1 = testarray`?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/24166170, "I am using `.copy()` to guarantee that you have contiguous data in memory. This would be unnecessary if positions was Fortran-contiguous.". So I'm guessing the `copy()` here is also to ensure contiguous memory