# Cython class numpy fixed size array declaration

Tags: python, cython

Im trying to initiate a fixed sized array within a cython class so multiple methods can use it. How can that be done?

```
cdef class My Class:
    cdef public np.ndarray[np.float, ndim=1] myarr
    def __cinit__(self,int history_length):
        self.myarr = np.empty(history_length, dtype=np.float)
```

I am getting an error saying:

`buffer types only allowed as function local variables`

Is there a way to declare this and access this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try defining it in the pxd as a class property?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838241/cython-says-buffer-types-only-allowed-as-function-local-variables-even-for-ndarr relevant?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the buffer syntax type[::1] is preferred in cython i.e.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef float[::1] myarr
    def __cinit__(self,int history_length):

        self.myarr = np.empty(history_length, dtype=np.float)
```

Edit: the above code assumes that you define  an array continuous in memory, which by default for numpy arrays is the c style (i.e. row continuous). Defining it float[:] would state that you are expecting a float buffer not necessarily continuous.

Comment: double[::1] which corresponds to the python float type

Comment: Not sure if that holds in cython, dtype can also be registered with double for example. But you are right that python doesn't have float and double distinction.